# Problem with layer dimensions when using Keras sequence generator and fit_generator

Tags: python, keras, generator

- I am running a visual **question answering task**.
- The problems take as ***input : image*** features (which I have saved in a
  `h5py` file)  and question tokens (which I have pickled) and outputs
  are the answers (the whole answer is considered a target , so 3129
  answers –one word or more - and 3129 labels)
- I am using the `Keras` sequence utility to create the `generator`.
- I am getting a dimension error in the output layer when the model
  is training. when I change the **len** function, based on its value the training process breaks down
- I have copied my getitem function in the generator and also a sample
  of my model.

Do I need to ***change*** my generator configuration or my model?

```
Epoch 1/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-45-e55a5853e499>", line 32, in <module>
    validation_data=valid_generator)
  File "C:\python\envs\tf2-keras\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\envs\tf2-keras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\python\envs\tf2-keras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 220, in fit_generator
    reset_metrics=False)
  File "C:\python\envs\tf2-keras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1508, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\python\envs\tf2-keras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 621, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\python\envs\tf2-keras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected output to have shape (3129,) but got array with shape (1,)
def __len__(self):
'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
# return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))
return 512*866

# this is the getitem function 
The __getitem__ of my generator look like this:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'

        imfeatures      = np.empty((self.batch_size,2048))
        question_tokens = np.empty((self.batch_size,14))
        answers         = np.empty((self.batch_size,3129))

        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]
        # self.T.append(indexes)
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        for i,k in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            temp =self.Features['image_features'][k]
            imfeatures[i,]=temp[0,:]
            question_tokens[i,]=self.Questions[indexes[i]]
            answers=self.Answer[indexes[i]]

        return [imfeatures,question_tokens],answers
# this is  where I instantiate the generators
#train_features is h5py file 
# entries is where questions, answers, and ids are saved
batch_size=512
train_generator  = DataGenerator(entries['train'].images,
                                  train_fetures,
                                  entries['train'].q_token,
                                  entries['train'].target,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  shuffle = False)

valid_generator  = DataGenerator(entries['val'].images,
                                  valid_features,
                                  entries['val'].q_token,
                                  entries['val'].target,
                                  batch_size=batch_size,
                                  shuffle = False) 
#And this is what my model looks like:

ImInput = Input(shape=(2048,),name='image_input')
QInput = Input(shape=(14,),name='question')

# some dense layers and dropouts

#Then the layers are merged

M =Multiply()[ImInput,QInput]
#Some dense layers and dropouts

output=Dense(3129,activation='softmax',name='output')(M)

model = Model([ImInput,QInput ],output)
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              epochs=1,
                              verbose =1,
                              validation_data=valid_generator)
```

Comment: Please display where you instantiate your `train_generator`. It would be useful to know its shape too.

Comment: I added train_generator instantiation

Comment: I also added the __len__ function which seems to be causing the problem

Comment: I suppose you created your `DataGenerator`, and  `train_generator` is a `Sequence`. I think you must have a problem with the shape of your labels. What is the shape of `entries['train'].target` and `entries['val'].target` ?

Comment: Check this link also : https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly